# FileSystemWatcher Deleted event raises only sometimes

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I tested this code nearly 30 times and i saw the message in the console only 10-15 times. (which must appear when event raised).

```
    string fileToWatchFor = "file.txt";
    var inputedFileInfo = new FileInfo(fileToWatchFor);

    FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher
        = new FileSystemWatcher(inputedFileInfo.DirectoryName);
    fileSystemWatcher.Filter = "*.txt";
    fileSystemWatcher.Deleted += delegate (object sender, FileSystemEventArgs eventArgs)
        { Console.WriteLine("I was invoked when you file was deleted!"); };
    fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    File.Create(fileToWatchFor).Close();
    File.Delete(fileToWatchFor);
```

I read many answers and tried to do the following :

```
GC.KeepAlive(fileSystemWatcher);
```

But it didn't help anyway. I run VS with Administrator permission.
I've got Windows 10, VS 2017, run project in Debug mode using .NET Framework 4.6.1.
The directory of the `inputedFileInfo.DirectoryName` is right and the result of the `File.Create(fileToWatchFor)` is placed in this directory. (I've checked many times).

Comment: You'd have to be lucky to see that message.  Consider adding Console.ReadLine().

Comment: I did it and now see this message every time! Can you explain me why?

Comment: Can you give some more context? Console? WinForms? Have you set a `NotifyFilters` (`NotifyFilters.FileName`, especially)? Are you setting a `.SynchronizingObject`?

Comment: I'm having a psychic debugging day today, been on a roll all morning.  It is a threading race if you let your Main() method exit too soon, before the thread that FSW starts to tell you about the deletion had a chance to run.  A normal program that uses FSW of course does not instantly quit, so you basically stopped programming too early.

Comment: I understand thank you. If you add this information as answer, i will mark it as answer.